# How to set the Expander to center to the left

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, expander

Ok So I have an expander that needs to expand down and that works fine however it aligns the content to the right like so: [display of the expander](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9wqR.jpg) I would prefer that it ether aligns to the center or to the left.

[image]

I have tried changing the `ExpandDirection` property but that just changes what direction the expander opens.

Here is the code for the expander:

```
<Expander x:Name="shifts" Margin="0,0,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ExpandDirection="Down" AllowDrop="False">
                                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <local:ShiftControl/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Expander>
```

and here is the code for the shift control

```
<DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                            <TextBox x:Name="ShiftName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=ShiftName,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" IsEnabled="False"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="JobType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,0,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=JobType,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61" IsEnabled="False"/>
                            <mah:TimePicker x:Name="Clockout" Height="23" Width="95" Margin="0,0,5,5" SelectedTimeFormat="Short" IsEnabled="False"  SelectedTime="{Binding Path= ShiftStartTime, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <mah:TimePicker x:Name="Clockin" Height="23" Width="95" Margin="0,0,5,5" SelectedTimeFormat="Short" IsEnabled="False" SelectedTime="{Binding Path= ShiftEndTime, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="notes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,0,5,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Notes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

I am looking for a way to align the content to either the center or the left

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To align the content of a `Control` (in this case the `Expander`) use the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` properties. See the [bottom section of the Expander documentation on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/expander-overview#using-the-alignment-properties).

You may also need to set the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the containing `StackPanels` (either the one inside the `Expander` or the one inside your shift control).